# Return downloadable file in PHP to Internet Explorer with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, php, internet-explorer, download

I have a PHP web application in which users can click a button to download an XML file generated on the fly. It has worked well for a long time, but suddenly I am getting bug reports from a single Internet Explorer user (I only have a screenshot showing the bug). I need your help to figure out possible causes.

First, the button click in the web GUI is handled with jQuery which has a JavaScript `window.location` statement:

```
$("#generate-button").click(function() {
    ...
    window.location = "generateXml.phtml";
}
```

`generateXml.phtml` is PHP which creates an XML string which is returned:

```
header('Content-Type: application/xml');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=xmlFile.xml');
echo $xmlString;
```

Up until now, users have always been prompted whether to open or save the `xmlFile.xml` (which is correct). Now however, a user of Internet Explorer (version unknown but it appears to be IE10) is prompted whether to open or save `generateXml_phtml`:

[image]

Note that IE has replaced the `.` (dot) with `_` (underscore). It seems the PHP server code in `generateXml.phtml` is not even executed.

Do you have any ideas? I cannot replicate the bug using IE on my own system.

Answer (score 1):

Can you give a direct link to the problem? Try change the extenssion to .php its weird if the file ins´t being processed the web server should only give you a executed code not the raw code, maybe is something wrong with .phtml extenssion...

Comment: Unfortunately the GUI requires authentication so I cannot provide a link. I agree that changing the file extension is worth a shot.

Comment: if you change it to .php i bet it wouldn´t give you the raw code just the processed one.

Comment: Still, I cannot understand why this would affect just a single Internet Explorer client. (It will take some time before I can ask the client to test again.)

Comment: Was just told that the bug persists for the client, despite the changed extension.

Comment: The user cant save your file? if he save it is it empty?